# Learning fluid simulation with blender 2.82, can't get the water mesh where i want?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to learn the fluid simulations on Blender 2.82. I want to splash some water on the ground, but unfortunately, the mesh is always above the ground, it's like there is some offset between the data particles and the mesh.
[image]

I've been told to switch to 2.83 because they fixed the offset bug, but it's still the same, looks like it's not really a bug (or maybe it is) but maybe i'm just doing it wrong, any idea?

Comment: There is a setting that's called margin and it basicly is the offset to the object. You could try to reduce that

Comment: I only see the margin setting for the GAS, but i'm simulating LIQUID